# How do I convert NSOpenPanel.URL to a string?

Tags: macos, swift

I was trying to display an open file dialog in OSX via Xcode and Swift.
I then wanted to put the filename in a TextField.

I started with

```
@IBOutlet weak var lblFileName: NSTextField!
@IBAction func FileOpen(sender: AnyObject) {   
    var f:NSOpenPanel = NSOpenPanel()
    f.title = "open that file"
    f.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    f.canChooseDirectories = false
    f.runModal()
    var thefile = f.URLs[0].absoluteString
    println(thefile)
    //failed: lblFileName.stringValue = thefile
    lblFileName.stringValue = "I want this to be the filename!"
}
```

println(thefile) worked, so it was just an issue with converting the URL
The variable "thefile" wasn't a string and all attempts to cast it failed.

I did get it working so I thought I'd post the answer here as well.

Comment: var thefile:NSString = f.URLs[0].absoluteString!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code that ended up working
note I created a string named mystring and had to use the ? and the ! to get things to work.
If there's an easier/better way please add that in the comments!

```
@IBOutlet weak var lblFileName: NSTextField!
@IBAction func FileOpen(sender: AnyObject) {   
    var f:NSOpenPanel = NSOpenPanel()
    f.title = "open that file"
    f.allowsMultipleSelection = false
    f.canChooseDirectories = false
    f.runModal()
    var thefile = f.URLs[0].absoluteString
    println(thefile)
    var mystring:String? = thefile
    lblFileName.stringValue = mystring!
}
```